# How do I trigger SSM Run Command/document on two different schedules using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to run a command that creates backups of drives on an ec2 windows instance, this commands should be run on two different schedules, one which runs hourly and the other once every 24 hours. Currently I pass a schedule expression to my association which runs hourly. I want to be able to create two schedules which i will be able to view on the AWS systems manager dashboard. I am not sure if i can leverage Maintenance window here.

```
resource aws_ssm_document backup_script {
  name          = "backup_script"
  document_type = "Command"

  content = <<DOC
  {
    "schemaVersion": "1.2",
    "description": "execute snapshot script",
    "parameters": {

    },
    "runtimeConfig": {
      "aws:runPowerShellScript": {
        "properties": [
          {
            "id": "0.aws:runPowerShellScript",
            "runCommand": ["powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file 'C:\\backup.ps1'"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
DOC
}

resource aws_ssm_association backup_script {
  name = aws_ssm_document.backup_script.name

  targets {
    key    = "tag:backup"
    values = ["${var.backup}"]
  }

  schedule_expression = "rate(60 minutes)"
}
```